# Description error returning on messages sent through Apache mod_proxy

Tags: java, xml, apache, mod-proxy, ibm-integration-bus

I'm having an issue with the description of the error messages returned by some IIB (IBM Integration Bus) applications sending messages to an endpoint through an apache mod_proxy gateway.

When I sent the message directly to endpoint (without apache) I receive the correct error description: "WEBSERVICE ERROR : W2000101 : Web Service not found".

But if this same message is sent through apache (mod_proxy) the description error is returned by a java message, like below:

```
<NS2:Fault xmlns:NS2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <faultcode>ESB2003</faultcode>
    <faultstring>Ocorreu um erro ao acionar o sistema Protheus. Consulte o campo de detalhes para mais informações.</faultstring>  
     <faultactor>ConsultarTituloPrevistoP12.Soap Request P12</faultactor>
     <detail><Text>Axis2Requester_processResponseMessageSync, org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: White space is required between quot;SYSTEMquot; and the system identifier., Frame : 0 org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: White space is required between quot;SYSTEMquot; and the system identifier.| @: org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.nextStAXOMBuilder.java:293| @: org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.getSOAPEnvelopeStAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:204| @: org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.amp;lt;initamp;gt;StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:154| @: org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.amp;lt;initamp;gt;StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:140| @: com.ibm.broker.axis2.SoapUtilities.createSOAPMessageSoapUtilities.java:2259| @: com.ibm.broker.axis2.SoapUtilities.createSOAPMessageSoapUtilities.java:1959| @: com.ibm.broker.axis2.Axis2Requester.processResponseMessageSyncAxis2Requester.java:2184| @: com.ibm.broker.plugin.MbOutputTerminal._propagateNative Method| @: com.ibm.broker.plugin.MbOutputTerminal.propagateMbOutputTerminal.java:133| @: com.ibm.broker.plugin.MbOutputTerminal.propagateMbOutputTerminal.java:88| @: com.ibm.broker.ct.mapping.MappingNode.buildAndPropagateMappingNode.java:1118| @: com.ibm.broker.ct.mapping.MappingNode.evaluateMappingNode.java:409| @: com.ibm.broker.plugin.MbNode.evaluateMbNode.java:1453|Frame : 1 javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: White space is required between quot;SYSTEMquot; and the system identifier.| @: com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.stax.msg.StAXMessageProvider.throwWrappedXMLStreamExceptionStAXMessageProvider.java:76| @: com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.stax.XMLStreamReaderImpl.produceFatalErrorEventXMLStreamReaderImpl.java:2008| @: com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.jaxb.JAXBXMLStreamReader.produceFatalErrorEventJAXBXMLStreamReader.java:356| @: com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.scan.DocumentScanner.reportFatalErrorDocumentScanner.java:4871| @: com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.scan.DTDScanner.reportFat</Text></detail></NS2:Fault>
```

The mod_proxy is configured just to redirect the messages, there's haven't any treatment or change in the apache.

Comment: The error text it's an xml fragment, try to post the complete error please.

Comment: I've edited the text and put the completed xml now. Thanks.